# Tournament Bracket Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Creating a tournament bracket that will act as a form. User will choose winners from round one and I want each prior round to populate the dropdowns for the next round. I have tried a few solutions but can't get it to work. Below is the code.

```js
$(window).ready(function() {

        $('#G17W').on('click', function() {
            console.log($('.team').val());
            $('#G17W').html('');
            if ($('#G1W').val() == 1 && $('#G2W').val() == 8) {
                $('#G17W').append('<option value="">Select</option>');
                $('#G17W').append('<option value="NoDa Brewing">NoDa Brewing</option>');
                $('#G17W').append('<option value="Salud Cerveceria">Salud Cerveceria</option>');
            }
            else if ($('#G1W').val() == 1 && $('#G2W').val() == 9) {
                $('#G17W').append('<option value="">Select</option>');
                $('#G17W').append('<option value="NoDa Brewing">NoDa Brewing</option>');
                $('#G17W').append('<option value="Cabarrus Brewing Co.">Cabarrus Brewing Co.</option>');
            }
            else if ($('#G1W').val() == 16 && $('#G2W').val() == 8) {
                $('#G17W').append('<option value="">Select</option>');
                $('#G17W').append('<option value="Three Spirits Brewery">Three Spirits Brewery</option>');
                $('#G17W').append('<option value="Salud Cerveceria">Salud Cerveceria</option>');
            }
            else if ($('#G1W').val() == 1 && $('#G2W').val() == 9) {
                $('#G17W').append('<option value="">Select</option>');
                $('#G17W').append('<option value="Three Spirits Brewery">Three Spirits Brewery</option>');
                $('#G17W').append('<option value="Cabarrus Brewing Co.">Cabarrus Brewing Co.</option>');
            } else {
                $('#G17W').append('<option value="">Select</option>');
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="G1W" name="G1W">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">NoDa Brewing</option>
  <option value="16">Three Spirits Brewery</option>
</select>

<select id="G2W" name="G2W">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="8">Salud Cerveceria</option>
  <option value="9">Cabarrus Brewing Co.</option>
</select>

<select id="G17W" name="G17W">
  <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

### Problem

`$('#G17W').html('');` destroys all options every time `<select id='G17W'>` is clicked. If you click and use the arrow keys, it will change to the appropriate option. This of course is not desirable.

---

### Solution

1. Do not use `append()` to change tags an arbitrary amount of times. DOM operations such as removing and adding tags is costly.
2. Do not use `.html()` to remove tags unless you do not plan to add any tags afterwards. `.html()` is destructive -- if there are any references that pointed at any destroyed tags the references remain. This may lead to unpredictable behavior.
3. Add blank `<options>` and just assign values and text to each `<option>`. Unlike DOM manipulation, assigning attribute values and text content is less likely to cause adverse side-effects nor is it as costly. To avoid the blanks showing up hide them when they have no value and text then show them when they do.
4. Register the `change` event on the first two `<select>`s. When either one of the first two `<select>` changes, the third `<select>` will as well.

---

### Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var t1 = `NoDa Brewing`;
  var t16 = `Three Spirits Brewery`;
  var t8 = `Salud Cerveceria`;
  var t9 = `Cabarrus Brewing Co.`;

  var g1 = $('#G1W');
  var g2 = $('#G2W');
  var g1g2 = $('#G1W, #G2W');
  var g17 = $('#G17W');

  g1g2.on('change', function() {
    var v1 = g1.val();
    var v2 = g2.val();

    if (v1 === '1') {
      g17.find('option').eq(1).val(t1).text(t1).show();
    } else if (v1 == '16') {
      g17.find('option').eq(1).val(t16).text(t16).show();
    }
    if (v2 === '8') {
      g17.find('option').eq(2).val(t8).text(t8).show();
    } else if (v2 == '9') {
      g17.find('option').eq(2).val(t9).text(t9).show();
    }
    if (v1 === '0') {
      g17.find('option').eq(1).val('').text('').hide();
    }
    if (v2 === '0') {
      g17.find('option').eq(2).val('').text('').hide();
    }
    g17.val('0');
    return;
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="G1W" name="G1W">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">NoDa Brewing</option>
  <option value="16">Three Spirits Brewery</option>
</select>

<select id="G2W" name="G2W">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="8">Salud Cerveceria</option>
  <option value="9">Cabarrus Brewing Co.</option>
</select>

<select id="G17W" name="G17W">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="" style='display:none'></option>
  <option value="" style='display:none'></option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, the code seems to be fine. Tried running the exact code, it is returning the output as expected. You can try by running the snippet here below your code. Please elaborate if your ask is something else.

Thought there is a scope of optimizing the above code.

Cheers.

Comment: The third dropdown does not let you select an option though.